# Refresh TextBoxes on TextChanged Event

Tags: c#, ado.net

```
private void txtItems_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand();
      MySqlDataReader read;
      com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Inventory where ProductID ='" + txtbCode.Text + "'";
      com.Connection = MySQLConnection.con;
      MySQLConnection.con.Open();
      read = com.ExecuteReader();
      while (read.Read())
      {
         txtCatogery.Text = read["Catogery"].ToString();
         txtDiscriptions.Text = read["Description"].ToString();
         txtQTY.Text = read["QTY"].ToString();
         txtPrice.Text = read["Price"].ToString();
      }
    //Rest of code
   }
}
```

When I type a barcode in `txtbCode` the TextBoxes are get in the values from db, but if I have a product with bar code `1234` continue typing 56 (123456) I have no products with that bar code but the values of the textboxes wont refresh, they keep the values that are read about 1234.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: using `MySqlCommand` in textChanged event.. is not advisable

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple issues with this code, but to answer you primary question, it's because of your `while (read.Read())` line.  If they query returns `0` rows, the `while statement` will never execute.

If you're expecting a single row, you should make it an `if (read.Read())` instead, and the add an `else` condition to clear the text boxes.

Other issues you might want to look into are making sure you dispose the reader when you're done with it, and using parameters instead of embedding user input directly into the query.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should *parametrize* you queries - see **[Sql Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**.

Regarding your question, you should clear the previous values BEFORE quering the DB, since in your current code, the textboxes are updated only if the Read() succeeded (e.g. you have a row in the DB) ... But if you have no rows it won't get updated and the previous entries will remain.

```
 private void txtbCode_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     txtCatogery.Text = String.Empty;
     txtDiscriptions.Text = String.Empty;
     ...

     try
     {
        MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand();
        MySqlDataReader read;
        .....
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the returning values from your query, if no value returned, clear your `Textboxes`

```
        MySQLConnection.con.Open();
        read = com.ExecuteReader();
    if(read != null)
    {
        while (read.Read())
        {
        txtCatogery.Text = read["Catogery"].ToString();
        txtDiscriptions.Text = read["Description"].ToString();
        txtQTY.Text = read["QTY"].ToString();
        txtPrice.Text = read["Price"].ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        txtCatogery.Text = "";
        txtDiscriptions.Text =  "";
        txtQTY.Text =  "";
        txtPrice.Text =  "";
    }
```

Beer in mind that your code may produce some bugs, as an example if multiple records returned from the database, your `TextBoxes` will only show the last record data. If any record has null fields it will generate an error because of your `.ToString()`. Finally `SQL injection` is a major threat unless you're writing this code for learning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.HasRows`](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDataReader~HasRows.html) before you can go [`.Read()`](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDataReader.html)

```
...
MySqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
if (read.HasRows) 
{ 
  while (read.Read())
  {
      //Do Stuff
  }
}
else
{
   //Do Stuff
   txtPrice.Clear();
}
```